# How to gzip a file

Tags: linux, shell, gzip, gunzip

How can I gzip this file? I get an error:

```
find /users/tnea01/logfile10.log -type f -exec sh -c \ 'gunzip /users/tnea01/logfile_archive/$(basename $0)_$(date -r {} +%F).gz $0' {} \;
```

Here is the error I get:

> gzip: /users/tnea01/logfile10.tar.gz: No such file or directory gzip: /users/tnea01/logfile10.log: unknown suffix -- ignored

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Does you find command work without the exec command?

Comment: Here is the error I get:

gzip: /users/tnea01/logfile10.tar.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: /users/tnea01/logfile10.log: unknown suffix -- ignored

Comment: Why use `find` at all if you know the exact filename?

Comment: Is there a better way  Charles Duffy 29? I need to gzip the file with the last modified date

Comment: Why do you need to GZIP? You can `cp` the file to another with the date.

Comment: @cricket_007, compressing files when rotating them is a very sensible practice.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Now it makes sense

Comment: `gunzip[...]: unknown suffix` means that `gunzip` is trying to look at the filename to figure out how to decompress it (it's a **un**zip command, after all), but the filename is a `.log` file, not a `.gz` or `.Z`. Presumably you meant to use `gzip` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you *didn't* know the exact filename, you might do something like this:

```
find /users/tnea01 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.log' -type f -exec sh -c \
    'for f; do
       gzip -c <"$f" >"/users/tnea01/logfile_archive/${f##*/}_$(date -r "$f" +%F).gz"
     done' _ {} +
```

To explain the moving pieces:

- The only secure way to use `sh -c` is with a completely constant string; substituting variables into it (including filenames) creates security vulnerabilities. Thus, we don't use any kind of replacement facility in the code, but pass the filename(s) as extra arguments.
- `for f; do` is the same as `for f in "$@"; do` -- it iterates over all command line arguments.
- `${f**#/}` evaluates to everything after the last `/` in `$f`; see [the bash-hackers page on parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).
- Expansions, including `$(date ...)`, need to be inside a double-quoted context to be safe; here, we're putting the entire destination filename in such quotes.

---

However, since you do, that's all entirely needless.

```
f=/users/tnea01/logfile10.log
d=/users/tnea01/logfile_archive
gzip -c <"$f" >"$d/${f##*/}_$(date -r "$f" +%F).gz"
```

Comment: Thank you Charles Duffy ! There are actually 2 files that need to be backed up so I used your first suggesting that worked perfectly. I have one more question which is no big deal if it requires too much work. My current log file is called logfile.log.10 which then rolls off and gets deleted. is it possible to modify it so it only says logfile.log + last modified date.gz? Basically using the current log file name minus the .10 at the end. Thank you again!!!

Comment: @connollyc4, by "last modified date" you mean looking at which logfiles exist in the directory, finding the latest one that actually exists, and expanding to that? You'd want to follow BashFAQ #3 for identifying that file; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003

Comment: Sorry I think I didn't explain that right. The log file is called "logfile.log.10 which I want to use the same script as your first suggestion with the find command but rename it to logfile.log + the date and time as it already does with date -r "$f" +%F).gz"

Comment: so that's to say that the change from current behavior is you want to strip the `.10` before appending the suffix?

Comment: exactly,

so the current log file is called "logfile.log.10 while the script you provided would call it "logfile.log.10-2016-07-29.gz" which I was hoping to strip the .10 suffix and have it named logfile.log.-2016-07-29.gz.

Comment: so, that would be something like `f_base=${f##*/}; f_base=${f_base%%.[[:digit:]]*}; gzip -c <"$f" >"$d/${f_base}_$(date -r "$f" +%F).gz"`

Comment: ...and, to be clear, everything I just used in the above comment is explained in the link I gave in the answer, http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe. You *did* follow that link, right? :)